# Angular Effects Unit test: RxJs race operator

Tags: angular, testing, ngrx, effect

I am trying to write unit test for an ngRX effects in an angular project.

The effect uses switchMap to return a race operator.
The race operator either looks for a 3sec timer to complete or looks an ngRX action event to be dispatched to mirror the observable. It then pipes that to another switchMap to return an ngRX action to be dispatched.

Code example:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(....some action...)
  switchMap(.. => {
    return race(
     this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(....some other action....),
       take(1),
       switchMap(n => {
         return of(true);
       }),
     ),
     timer(3000).pipe(
      switchMap(n => {
       return of(false);
      }),
     )
    ).pipe(
      switchMap(... => {
            return [SomeGroup.action()];
          }),
    )
  })
```

How can I write the unit test for this?

Tried fakeAsync, tick and flush but the test only reached upto the return point to the race op, but not getting the inner timer or action checker reached and subsequent switchMap to return the final action.

Comment: I think I got the issue. It was the way I was trying to use the Observable stream. Used ReplaySubject with buffer size 2 to get it working.

Comment: Please show your answer and accept it instead of leaving a comment.